# I am having a tracking issue in Blender

Tags: animation, tracking

No matter how many trackers I put and how much I align the scene I just can't seem to get a good track for my object. Every time the camera moves right or left, the object moves with the camera rather than remain still in it's spot, like tracking should do.

Does anyone have any idea why? I have tried previous solutions including setting orientation, scale and all that but nothing is working. It's literally not even that hard of a scene.

Comment: We would need quite a bit more informations than that. For starters, what is your *Solve Error* ? Adding screenshots and your blend file would increase your chances.

Comment: Solve error, is relative low. Also, I apologize, I was frustrated writing this. I found out that using a different Model Match is much better, because I was using location tracking only. Which means, I think i've solved my own problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)